# Amplitude for sum of sinusoids

Tags: trigonometry, absolute-value

I am trying to plot the following function:
$$
\max_t \left| \frac{1}{1-r^2} \big( \sin(r \omega_n t) - r \sin(\omega_n t)\big) \right|
$$
By inspection, I have determined that the amplitude of the sum of the sin terms is independent of $\omega_n$, but I haven't been able to find an expression for the amplitude.

Comment: By taking the derivative, you can see that the maxima and minima occur when $\cos(r\omega_nt) = \cos(\omega_nt)$. Examine those points to see what the maximum value of the expression is.

Answer (score 0):

If
$f(t)
= \sin(r a t) - r \sin(a t)
$,
then the extreme values
will be at $t$
such that
$f'(t) = 0$.

Find these values,
and look at $f(\text{these values)}$.

Comment: Yes, this leads me to cos(rat) = cos(at), from which follows at = 2n pi / (1-r), 2n pi / (-1-r).  However, plugging this solution back in will give me inflection points and local maxima in addition to the amplitude.  I'm still lost trying to find an expression for amplitude

Answer (score 0):

If $r^2 \lt 1$ the first factor is positive and you have $\max_t \left| \frac{1}{1-r^2} \big( \sin(r \omega_n t) - r \sin(\omega_n t)\big) \right|=\frac{1}{1-r^2}\max_t \left| \big( \sin(r \omega_n t) - r \sin(\omega_n t)\big) \right|$ and the absolute value will be maximal when the sines are properly $\pm 1$ depending on the sign of $r$.  The absolute value will then be $1+|r|$ and the overall value will be $\frac 1{1-|r|}$.  You need to convince yourself that you can get the sines to work out this way.  If $r^2 \gt 1$ the factor you pull out is $\frac 1{r^2-1}$ and you get a final answer of $\frac 1{|r|-1}$ for the same reason.

Comment: Depending on $r$ and $\omega_n$, the two sines may never both be 1 or -1.

Comment: Yes, this only works when r = 1 - 2n for some n, so r must be an integer?

Comment: If $r$ is irrational, you can approach this arbitrarily closely.  If $r$ is a negative rational I think you can always do it because you want the signs of the sines to match.  I haven't resolved when $r$ is a positive rational.